# Cache bust response with etag

Tags: javascript, caching, server

For a while, a server was sending me some bad data. It was sending a 200 OK response, but no content body. And browser caching made the issue persist for users who visited during that time window. At first I thought I could resolve the issue by appending a cache buster to the URL, something like `?cacheBuster=<UUID>`, but that didn't solve the issue. Browsers were still pulling from their cache. My best guess is because the response has an etag, and browsers are looking up the cached response by the etag rather than by the URL. Assuming my guess is right, how can I force browsers to re-fetch a resource that, according to the etag, they think they already have?

Comment: That's not how etag works. Your server is checking the etag, the browser won't use the cache unless your server tell it to do so by telling your browser the etag has not changed. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag

Comment: @mpm And the server is indeed claiming the etag has not changed, even though the content has, because at some earlier time, the server sent back a malformed response that was missing the content body.